# Firebase Flutter Refresh issue

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a live Flutter App that uses firebase Datastore.

- When the user is logged out and I make changes to the user doc and the user logs back in the changes I have made in the firestore database stay. ( Correct function )
- When the user is logged in and using the app and I make changes to the user doc the changes I have made in the firestore database stay. ( Correct function )
- ** When the user is logged in and backgrounds the app by using another app or locking the phone and I make changes to the user doc then the user resumes the app the data I have changed in the user doc reverts to the old data. ** ( incorrect function ) this only happens on a real device and not and emulator.

What is the issue I have tried incorporating this code in the main then i tried incorporating it in other screens of the app. Sent to test flight and issue is still present.

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      userState.refreshUserData();
      topicsManager();
      print('App resumed - refreshing data');
    }
  } 


  @action
  Future<void> refreshUserData() async {
    try {
      print('Refreshing user data...');

      final docSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(USERS_COLLECTION)
          .doc(docId) // Ensure 'docId' is correctly set
          .get(GetOptions(
              source: Source.server)); 

      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic> latestUserData =
            docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        Map<String, dynamic> latestUserBeeInfo =
            latestUserData['beeInfo'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        String? latestBeeType = latestUserBeeInfo['beeType'];

        // Directly compare necessary fields or utilize a method if complex logic is needed
        // For simplicity, assuming direct field checks here:
        if (me.displayName != latestUserData['displayName'] ||
            me.email != latestUserData['email'] ||
            me.userBeeInfoField.beeType != latestBeeType) {
          loadUser(latestUserData, docId);
          print('User data updated with fresh data.');
        } else {
          print('No changes in user data detected.');
        }
      } else {
        print('User data document does not exist.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error refreshing user data: $e');
    }
  }

What is the issue I have tried incorporating this code in the main then i tried incorporating it in other screens of the app. Sent to test flight and issue is still present.  

 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      userState.refreshUserData();
      topicsManager();
      print('App resumed - refreshing data');
    }
  } 


  @action
  Future<void> refreshUserData() async {
    try {
      print('Refreshing user data...');

      final docSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(USERS_COLLECTION)
          .doc(docId) // Ensure 'docId' is correctly set
          .get(GetOptions(
              source: Source.server)); 

      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic> latestUserData =
            docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        Map<String, dynamic> latestUserBeeInfo =
            latestUserData['beeInfo'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        String? latestBeeType = latestUserBeeInfo['beeType'];

        // Directly compare necessary fields or utilize a method if complex logic is needed
        // For simplicity, assuming direct field checks here:
        if (me.displayName != latestUserData['displayName'] ||
            me.email != latestUserData['email'] ||
            me.userBeeInfoField.beeType != latestBeeType) {
          loadUser(latestUserData, docId);
          print('User data updated with fresh data.');
        } else {
          print('No changes in user data detected.');
        }
      } else {
        print('User data document does not exist.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error refreshing user data: $e');
    }
  }
```

This is my authgate which is where the app goes on resume

````
      final bool isGoogleSignIn;
      final bool isAppleSignIn;
      final String? phoneNumber;
      const AuthGate(
          {Key? key,
          this.isGoogleSignIn = false,
          this.phoneNumber,
          this.isAppleSignIn = false})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return UserDataProvider(userId: snapshot.data!.uid);
            } else {
              return Homedashboard(); // Non-authenticated entry point
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class UserDataProvider extends StatefulWidget {
      final String userId;
      final bool isGoogleSignIn;
      final bool isAppleSignIn;
      final String? phoneNumber;
    
      const UserDataProvider({
        Key? key,
        required this.userId,
        this.isGoogleSignIn = false,
        this.phoneNumber,
        this.isAppleSignIn = false,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _UserDataProviderState createState() => _UserDataProviderState();
    }
    
    class _UserDataProviderState extends State<UserDataProvider> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .doc(widget.userId)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists) {
                final userData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                final userDto = UserDto.decode(userData);
                userState.loadUser(
                    userDto,
                    snapshot.data!
                        .id); // Assuming loadUser is adapted to accept UserDto
                return Homedashboard(); // Authenticated entry point with user data loaded
              } else {
                if (widget.isGoogleSignIn || widget.isAppleSignIn) {
                  return NewUserOtherProvider(
                      dynamicEmail: SharedState().email ?? "");
                } else if (widget.phoneNumber != null) {
                  // Handle phone number sign-in logic here
                } else {
                  return const NewUserSignUp(); // Sign-up for other methods
                }
                return NewUserSignUp(); // Or any other appropriate widget for new users
              }
            }
    
            // While waiting for data or in case of an error
            return Loading(); // Placeholder for a loading widget
          },
        );
      }
    }```
````